# MultiValueDictKey Error when submitting a form

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django, I am working on a website where user can edit his profile (first name, last name, username, email) and also change his profile picture with a separate form. The profile picture form save file when submitted, but the updateform display 'MultiValueDicKeyError at /account/edit' 'profile_pic' when the form is submitted. Here is my views.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

class UpdateUserForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email')

class ProfilePic(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('profile_pic', )


def profile_edit_view(request):
    form = ProfilePic(request.Post or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            pp = form.save(commit=False)
            pp.user = request.user
            pp, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
            pp.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']
            pp.save()
            return redirect... 
    else:
         form = ProfilePic()

    updateform = UpdateUserForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if updateform.is_valid():
            updateform.save()
            return redirect.... 
    else:
         updateform = UpdateUserForm()

context = {'form':form, 'updateform':updateform}

return render(request, 'profile_edit.html' context)
```

Comment: Can you show full exception trace log?

Comment: @Charnel.. What do you mean by 'full exceptional trace log'?

Comment: can you post your forms and models too

Comment: @GistDomBlog I mean full error message that Django shows when error happens.

Comment: @Charnel..This is the full message. 'MultiValueDicKeyError at /account/edit' 'profile_pic'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just save your forms like this and let the django forms handle your fields.

```
  def profile_edit_view(request):
        profile_form = ProfilePic()
        updateform = UpdateUserForm()   
        if request.method == 'POST':
            profile_form = ProfilePic(request.POST, request.FILES)
            updateform = UpdateUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)   
            if profile_form.is_valid() and updateform.is_valid():
               updateform.save()
               profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
               profile.user = request.user
               profile.save()
               return redirect ...      
        return render(request, 'profile_edit.html' {'profile_form':profile_form,'updateform':updateform})
```

**UPDATE**

I think you haven't provided this in the project/settings

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and this in your proejct/urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
....
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Only the image is not saving.

Comment: How can I save the image when form is submitted?

Comment: @GistDomBlog Have you set the ```enctype``` attribute in the form in your html template? Something like ```<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST>```

Comment: @Chris.. Enctype="multipart/form-data" is set in the form